# Is it possible to track the question-to-answer ratio of users on a given site?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, users, statistics

I'm trying to run a query which takes the top, say, 50 users on a site (bonus points if you can edit this number when running the query), and outputs a table listing all of the users, how many questions and answers each one has posted, and the ratio of these two numbers.

I'm sure this is possible with SEDE, but I can't figure out how to make it work. Is this possible?

Comment: **short answer:** Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, e.g. with [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1020914/qa-ratio-for-top-users).

[image]

<sub>Interestingly, one can even write this query while in a traffic jam ...</sub>

Feel free to [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/fork/1020914/) it to experiment and don't forget to share interesting results :) As always, note that SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday morning, but for this query that shouldn't really be a problem.